# Add settimeout between my get ellements inside one function

Tags: javascript, html, onclick

I need to add a settimeout between the get elements not sure how to set this out can anyone help

```
<p id="demo" >Click me to change my HTML content (innerHTML).</p>

<p id="emo" >Click me to change my HTML content (innerHTML).</p>

<button id="addto4" style="display:none;" onclick="myFunction()">change</buton>

<button id="addto3" onclick="myFunction1()">change2</buton>


    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default"  onclick="myFunction2()">Add all</button>


    <script> function myFunction2() {
        document.getElementById('addto3').click(),
        document.getElementById('addto4').click(); } </script>
```

Comment: where your `addto3` and `addto4` object? I did not see the object on your html

Comment: They come from a loop in shopify in  with the id increasing by one each time  for an add all to cart form i just wanted to set an interval between the two click actions i can add a quick example which wont be add to  cart form but the principles will be the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to split your method in 2 and call the 2nd part after the timeout.

```
function f2(){
  document.getElementById('addto4').click();
}

function f1(){
  document.getElementById('addto3').click();
  setTimeout(f2, 3000);
}
```